# Is there a way to create a Clustered Index in Slick?

Tags: scala, hsqldb, slick, clustered-index

I'm using Slick to create an application which stores a bunch of records about songs in an Hsqldb database.

Currently my tables are defined as:

```
abstract class DBEnum extends Enumeration {

  def enum2StringMapper(enum: Enumeration) = MappedJdbcType.base[enum.Value, String](
    b => b.toString,
    i => enum.withName(i))
}

class Artist(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String)](tag, "ARTIST") {

  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("NAME", O.NotNull)

  def nameIndex = index("NAME_IDX", name, unique = true)

  def * = (id, name)
}

class Song(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, Int)](tag, "SONG") {

  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("NAME", O.NotNull)
  def artistId = column[Int]("ARTIST_ID")

  def artistFk = foreignKey("ARTIST_FK", artistId, TableQuery[Artist])(_.id)

  def idNameIndex = index("ID_NAME_IDX", (id, name), unique = true)

  def * = (id, name, artistId)
}

object BroadcastType extends DBEnum {

  implicit val BroadcastTypeMapper = enum2StringMapper(BroadcastType)

  type BroadcastType = Value
  val PLAYED = Value("Played")
  val NOW = Value("Now")
  val NEXT = Value("Next")
}

class Broadcast(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, Timestamp, BroadcastType.BroadcastType)](tag, "BROADCAST") {

  def songId = column[Int]("SONG_ID")
  def dateTime = column[Timestamp]("DATE_TIME")
  def broadcastType = column[BroadcastType.BroadcastType]("BROADCAST_TYPE")

  def pk = primaryKey("BROADCAST_PK", (songId, dateTime))

  def songFk = foreignKey("SONG_FK", songId, TableQuery[Song])(_.id)

  def * = (songId, dateTime, broadcastType)
}
```

I'm still just setting things up so not sure if it's correct but hopefully you get the idea.

Now what I want to do is keep my composite primary key on the Broadcast table but I want to create a clustered index on the timestamp. Most of my queries on that table will be filtered by ranges on the timestamp. Rows will be inserted with an increasing timestamp so there is minimal shuffling of records to maintain the physical order.

Is there any abstraction to create a clustered index in Slick? So far it seems like I'm going to have to fall back to using plain SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to use plain sql now. You can create a feature request or a PR: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues